# How to Host iPython nbconvert slides on GitHub Pages

Tags: python, slideshow, jupyter-notebook, reveal.js, nbconvert

I'm trying to host my iPython slides on GitHub pages and make it available publicly as a slideshow. I created the slide using:

```
jupyter nbconvert make_presentation.ipynb --to slides --post serve
```

which created `make_presentation.slides.html`. The slideshow works fine locally as expected. I configured a new GitHub repo and it successfully serve `Reveal.js` test page: http://richardafolabi.github.io/Presentation_js/index.html

However, once on GitHub pages, my slides only shows static html page instead of slideshow: http://richardafolabi.github.io/Presentation_js/make_presentation.slides.html

Both `index.html` and `make_presentation.slides.html` are in the same directory level.

Anyone has any idea why my slides work locally but  doesn't work remotely? What other hosting options are out there for iPython slides?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem are the paths to reveal.js assets. You are trying to load :

http://richardafolabi.github.io/Presentation_js/reveal.js/js/reveal.js

but the correct path is:

http://richardafolabi.github.io/Presentation_js/js/reveal.js

Try changing the paths to all assets and it will work ;-) **Remove 'reveal.js/'** of all of them.

**Or change the assets folder, maybe is faster.**

Comment: Do you mean I should delete `/reveal.js/` from `make_presentation.slides.html`? It's a long file. I moved assets into `/reveal.js/` instead to conform with `/reveal.js/js/reveal.js` as in my slides but problem is still same. I cleared cache too.

Comment: You have a merge request ;-)

Comment: I confirmed the `merge` request and also did a `git pull`. This is my first time doing git merge, pull. Kindly let me know what to do next. Thanks :)

Comment: I received this error msg just now: `The page build failed with the following error:

The submodule `reveal.js` was not properly initialized with a `.gitmodules` file. For more information, see https://help.github.com/articles/page-build-failed-missing-submodule.`

Comment: Try again, it was my fault! Mine is working well http://viroide.github.io/Presentation_js/make_presentation.slides.html#/

Comment: Oh wow! One silly question. To update my repo with yours, I do a `git fetch --all` or `git pull` or what's the sequence I need to do?

Comment: with `git pull` it's enough